# method Interface param as reference problems

Tags: c#, dispose

If anyone has a better title, let me know.

I made a DisposeHelper so instead of this:

```
private Something _thing;

void Dispose()
{
    if(_thing != null)
    {
        _thing.Dispose();
        _thing = null;
    }
}
```

... i could do this:

```
private Something _thing;

void Dispose()
{
    DiposeHelper.Dipose(ref _thing);
}
```

But apparently I can't feed DisposeHelper.Dispose an IDisposable as a reference, unless I cast Something as IDisposable, like so:

```
private Something _thing;

void Dispose()
{
    IDisposable d = _thing;
    DiposeHelper.Dipose(ref d);
}
```

...which would mean it doesn't then nullify the original field.

Here's a more abstract example. DoThis works, DoThat doesn't:

```
public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        Something o = new Something();

        DoThis(o);

        DoThat(ref o);
    }

    private void DoThis(IFoo obj) { }

    private void DoThat(ref IFoo obj) { }
}

public class Something : IFoo { }

public interface IFoo { }
```

Why can't I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the technical reason as to why you can't.

This works, however:

```
var o = new Something();
DoThat(ref o);

private void DoThat<T>(ref T obj) where T : class, IFoo { 
    obj = null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because parameter types for `ref` and `out` expressions have to match exactly. Imagine if DoThat actually had this implementation:

```
private void DoThat(ref IFoo obj)
{
    obj = new SomeOtherImplementationOfFoo();
}
```

Now this code:

```
Something o = new Something();
DoThat(ref o);
```

would end up with `o` referring to instance of `SomeOtherImplementationOfFoo` instead of `Something` - which clearly can't be right.

So that's why `ref` works the way it does - and Rob's answer gives a way of working round it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the type must be the exact type of the property.

Imagine you could pass a `Derived` as `Base` into a function by reference. Now the function assigns the parameter a new object which is a `Base` but not a `Derived`. Booom

```
private Derived d;

void Modify(ref Base b)
{
  b=new Base();
}

Modify(ref d);//Booom
```

The work-around is using a generic parameter as in Rob's answer.

```
public static void DisposeAndNull<T>(ref T x)
  where T:IDisposable
{
  x.Dispose();
  x=null;
}
```